# Different bitmap/raster shape gradient like this example?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, raster, bitmap

does anyone know how to achieve this, a gradient that is created from the different raster/bit map shapes? i am trying to recreate this in illustrator [image]

Comment: Why make clearly raster graphics in illustrator?

Comment: @Tetsujin but how would you create this, do you think it is a gradient that is then bitmapped?

Comment: editing comment… sec...

Comment: @joojaa would photoshop be more suitable for such a graphic? and traced as a vector at a later stage?

Comment: It's made entirely out of circles, in only three different sizes. Each 'background is simply a solid last half of each overall shape-set. Dots spaced; Regular dots getting larger; solid; solid. Consider only the left-most segment as one iteration, the rest is the same, repeated. This is the entirety of the 'red' section - https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b5Vr.png - BTW the 80's called & want their graphics back ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks, i can see that it is the same instance repeated, i am just trying to figure out how to create the first instance with circle/diamonds from a gradient. do you think its created by hand?

Comment: There are no diamonds. It is ***all*** circles. The diamonds are coincidental. Think in one colour.

Comment: First 3 sections are all the same size circles, just spaced differently. After that, each set of circles is twice the diameter of the set to its left. First two iterations are spaced with gaps, but on a grid, like a chess-board with only black squares. Next 3 sections are 'fullgrid' each one twice as large as the last. There are only 3 circle sizes in all.

Comment: BTW, I've no clue how to go about this, as I don't use Illustrator, but that's your method, drop circles into a grid. Look at a checkers [draughts] board. You just need circles that touch the edges.

Comment: I did a really really rough example over a grid in Photoshop. You probably need a tad more precision ;) https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mvxy.png

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is created from a gradient. As mentioned in comments it seems to just be a simple geometric pattern consisting of a lot of circles on top of some rectangles.

You *could* probably use all sorts of transform magic to make it easier, but here I just want to show you how to draw the pattern with the mouse and keyboard using *Ellipse Tool*, *Rectangle Tool* and taking advantage of *Smart Guides*.

#### The method

It's easier to show with an animation than to explain in words. The animation is real-time so as you see, it doesn't take long to make.

[image]

#### The result

[image]

Duplicate the pattern and change the colors to make something similar to the example you've posted.

Comment: Magnificent to see it executed in real-time by someone who knows what they're doing. Thank you for filling in the practical from my rough-approximation theory :))

Comment: @Tetsujin, I'm glad you liked it. I must admit I had to practice the routine a few times before being able to record an animation without errors. 

Comment: I had my suspicions, but no-one ever likes to broadcast the out-takes… unless you're going to consider a blooper reel for xmas ;)) Nicely done anyway.